# Como redireccionar a mi pagina web despues de enviar un correo?

Tags: javascript, html, api

tengo una duda. Estoy usando API service de formspree para enviar correo electronicos desde mi pagina web, el problema esta que cuando envio un correo, la API me redirecciona a la pagina web de FormSpree, tal como lo muestra la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no quiero que me suceda esto, como hago para cuando envia el correo, no me dirigue esta pagina?

coloco el codigo HTML:

```
                <form
                    action="https://formspree.io/EJEMPLO_CODIGO"
                    method="POST"
                    >
                    <div class="field half first">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input name="name"  type="text" value="NameTest">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field half">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input name="email" type="email" value="test2@hola.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message" >MessageTest</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <button class="button alt" type="submit">Send Email</button>
                    </ul>
                </form>
```

Soy nuevo en esto, si sabe de otra API que me permita enviar correo sin que me dirija a la pagina del servicio o algo mejor, son Bienvenidas sus sugerencias!

Answer (score 0):

Como puedes comprobar, en el [target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) de tu form, **estás enviando los datos a la URL de Formspree**, entonces es inevitable que suceda dicha redirección.

La única solución que veo sin cambiar tu proveedor de este servicio, es añadir a la etiqueta `<form>` el siguiente atributo: `target="_blank"` el cual hará que se abra en una nueva pestaña, y cuando el usuario lo cierre, estará aún en tu web.

```
<form action="https://ejemplo.com/EJEMPLO_CODIGO" method="POST" target="_blank">
```

Comment: conoces de algun otro proveedor de servicio de email free que no haga esto?

Comment: Osea me sirvio pero no como me lo esperaba, porque me abre la pagina en otra pestaña. Yo lo que quisiera es que en vez de abrirse la pagina, yo lo informe en un alert en mi pagina web

Comment: @FabianRico Lo siento, no conozco ninguno. Por otra parte, debes evitar realizar preguntas basadas en opinión, ya que no están permitidas en StackO.